# Java, Using a String in an array in elsewhere?

Tags: java, arrays, object, text

I am new at coding. I was doing a project but I was stuck. My code reads a sentence from a text file. It seperates the sentence and gets the second word and records it in an array. I need to use this word in another place but I couldn't do it.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Classroom {
    private String classname;

    public String getClassname() {
        return classname;
    }

    public void setClassname(String classname) {
        this.classname = classname;
    }

    public void classroomreader(String filename) {
        // This method gets the name for Classroom
        File text = new File("C:/classlists/" + filename + ".txt");
        Scanner scan;
        try {
            scan = new Scanner(text);
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            String classroomarray[] = line.split("\t");
            // ** right now classroomarray[1] has the word which I want.**

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my main class:

```
public class ProjectMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // I created an array with 3 Classroom object inside it.
        Classroom[] classarray = new Classroom[3];

        //I hope I did this correct.

        // I used classroomreader method on my first object.
        classarray[0].classroomreader("class1"); 

        // Now I need to use the word in classroomarray[1].
        classarray[0].setClassname(????)
    }
}
```

I tried: `classarray[0].setClassname(classroomarray[1]);` but it gave an error. How can I set the name for my first object?

Comment: a class name including "class" makes me want to cry...

Comment: @Tetramputechture: [Yo dawg](http://i.imgur.com/K59ORaK.jpg).

Comment: In the above code add return at the end of method.

Comment: @Tetramputechture why? It is a class that represents a real world classroom ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm making just few changes in your code.. try this....definitely this'll work

```
    class Classroom {
private String classname;
String classroomarray[]=null;//declare  classroomarray[] here 

public String getClassname() {
    return classname;
}

public void setClassname(String classname) {
    this.classname = classname;
}

public void classroomreader(String filename) {

    File text = new File("C:/classlists/" + filename + ".txt");
    Scanner scan;
    try {
        scan = new Scanner(text);
        String line = scan.nextLine();
         classroomarray = line.split("\t");


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

class ProjectMain {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

```
        Classroom[] classarray = new Classroom[3];


        //here you need to initialize all elements of the array
        classarray[0]=new Classroom();
        classarray[1]=new Classroom();
        classarray[2]=new Classroom();

        classarray[0].classroomreader("class1"); 


        classarray[0].setClassname(classarray[0].classroomarray[1]);

        System.out.println(classarray[0].getClassname());// here you'll surely get the the desired results
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, it worked! But I have a question. 
    classarray[0]=new Classroom();
    classarray[1]=new Classroom();
    classarray[2]=new Classroom();

-----And --------  

Classroom[] classarray = new Classroom[3];

aren't they the same thing?

For example : in Classroom[] classarray = new Classroom[3];
 didn't we already created 3 objects in Classroom class?

Comment: No, Your Original Code Just initialize an array object of type Classroom. Each element of this array is a reference to a Classroom object.you must have to create  Classroom object i.e. new Classroom() , and assign a reference for these objects to each element of the array.  if you skip it you'll get NullPointerException when calling any method of Classroom class using these references.

Comment: I need to make String classroomarray[]=null; variable "private". When I do this, I can't use it anymore in main class. I generated getters and setters but I couldn't use them...

Comment: private String classroomarray[]=null;
    
    public String[] getClassroomarray() {
  return classroomarray;
 }      and in main() method use replace with this code       classarray[0].setClassname(classarray[0].getClassroomarray()[1]);  No need to provide a setter for classroomarray[].

Answer (score 0):

Its a little hard for me to understand what your code in the top is doing.. that being said I believe if you have a private variable in your top class and then have an accessor method like

```
public String getPrivateFieldValue()
{
     return somePrivateFieldName;
}
```

Then you can can set the private variable in your main class when you find the value for it. In your main class you can then say:

```
Object.getPrivateFieldValue() to get that value
```

or in your situation:

```
classarray[0].setClassname(classroomreader.getPrivateFieldValue())
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi i suggest you declare

```
classroomarray[]
```

as a member variable. Then generate getters and setters.

Later you can do what you want by setting

```
classarray[0].setClassname(classarray[0].getClassroomarray[1]);
```

I'm trying to help you on the way you want it to be done, but i don't understand why you wanna it to be done like that.

Edit : Here is the code i'm talking about in the comments below

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Classroom {
 private String classname;

 public String getClassname() {
    return classname;
 }

 public void setClassname(String classname) {
    this.classname = classname;
 }

 public void classroomreader(String filename) {
    // This method gets the name for Classroom
    File text = new File("C:/classlists/" + filename + ".txt");
    Scanner scan;
    try {
        scan = new Scanner(text);
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        String classroomarray[] = line.split("\t");
        // ** right now classroomarray[1] has the word which I want.**
        this.classname = classroomarray[1];

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

And finally your main method should look like

```
public class ProjectMain {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // I created an array with 3 Classroom object inside it.
    Classroom[] classarray = new Classroom[3];
    classarray[0]=new Classroom();
    //I hope I did this correct.

    // I used classroomreader method on my first object.
    classarray[0].classroomreader("class1"); 

    // Now classname is already set
    System.out.println(classarray[0].getClassname());
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't have any other idea to do what I want. Can you suggest a better way to me ?

Comment: I don't understand why you want the classroomarray[] array the use it later to set the classname, you could make it simpler by setting the classname directly in the classname in the classroomreader method. 

The code should look like 

String classroomarray[] = line.split("\t");
this.classname = classroomarray[1];

That way you would avoid this line 
classarray[0].setClassname(????)

Comment: By doing that, I don't need setter for "classname" variable, right?

Comment: @Dosher: It's better to use a return value in this case instead of a field.

Comment: Right, but i doesn't hurt to keep that setter. You may need it later.

Comment: @Bartvbl, why would use a return value and use it to set a member property anyway?

Comment: @diokey: Because using a field means you are creating a dependency on what classroomreader() will do. If you first call the method, then read out its result from the field, you are depending on that a) the function sets the field, and b) that the class using the field calls classroomreader() prior to using the field's value. That's bad practice. It should not be possible to misuse your code. That is not possible with a return value, which is thus a better solution.

Comment: @Bartvbl I agree with your suggestion. Best and simple way to do it.

Comment: @diokey: Calling setClassName() with the result of classroomreader() is indeed also a dependency, so in this case the ideal solution would be to call classroomreader() from inside the class. So you're right about that.

Comment: @Bartvbl ideally we would like a static class with utils methods for reading and writing to a file, but i thought the suggested solution should be easy for Dosher

Comment: @diokey: That's a bit the problem with teaching people, isn't it? Do you teach it right the first time, or do you give them the easy way out at the expense of having to teach it again later?

Comment: @Bartvbl interesting question, i think you are right. But usually when someone asks a question here, he wants a quick answer on how to get what they are doing working. It is good to point out why you think what they are doing is wrong, but you have to give them joy of seeing one's little code working first (especially when you are a beginner)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies with the concept of scope. Whenever you create a variable, like classroomarray, java registers that the name of that variable then represents the value you assign to it (in simple terms).

Now what Scope means is that not all variables can be accessed from every place. Classroomarray is created inside classroomReader(), but does not get out of that function once it completes. In a way "lives" inside that function, and that's why you can't use it in the main() method.

If you want to use classroomarray inside the main() method, you'll need to transport it there through some means. There are multiple ways of doing this:

1. Create a field in ClassRoom, like `public String[] classroomarray`
2. Return the classroom array you read from the file from the classroomreader() function. Returning a value means that you're "sending back" a value to whatever code called the function in the first place. For example, add(a, b) would return the sum of a and b. You do this by changing:

   ```
   public void classroomreader(String filename)
   ```

   To:

   ```
   public String[] classroomreader(String filename)
   ```

   And change:

   ```
   String classroomarray[] = line.split("\t");
   ```

   To:

   ```
   return line.split("\t");
   ```

   Then, in the main() method, you can use:

   ```
   String[] classroomFile = classarray[0].classroomreader("class1");
   ```

   And use the contents as you please.

Comment: I did it as you said but "classroomreader" method gave an error. It says " This method must return a result of type String[]"

Comment: Right. That is because when an exception occurs (see the IOException?), java needs to know what it should return. You should at some point look into error handling, but for making this example work, let the final line of the method be ``return new String[]{};``, right after the catch block ends.

Comment: But right now I don't have the variable at  classroomarray[1]. How can I get it back?

Comment: In main(), right after the ``classarray[0].classroomreader("class1");`` call, try putting: ``classarray[0].setClassname(classroomFile[1]);``

Answer (score 0):

This is an Example,Hope you don't mind hard interpretation. Please add return to your method like this.

```
     public String[] demo()  //Added ()
     {
        String[] xs = new String[] {"a","b","c","d"}; //added []
        String[] ret = new String[4];
        ret[0]=xs[0];
        ret[1]=xs[1];
        ret[2]=xs[2];
        ret[3]=xs[3];
        return ret;
     }


 So your new code will be like this

 public String[] classroomreader(String filename) {
    // This method gets the name for Classroom
    File text = new File("C:/classlists/" + filename + ".txt");
    String[] classroomarray;
    Scanner scan;
    try {
        scan = new Scanner(text);
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        classroomarray = new String[] {line.split("\t")};//Change this
        // ** right now classroomarray[1] has the word which I want.**

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
  return classroomarray;
}
```

In Main method change this:

```
 String [] strArr = demo();//Calling method which returns value clasroomarray
 for ( int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
   System.out.println(strArr[3]);//Printing whatever index you want

//Set Values here like this
Classroom classroom=new Classroom();//Initialize your object class
classroom.set(strArr[3]); //Set value
```

Comment: I tried it but it said "classroomarray cannot be resolved to a variable" . Why I got an error like that ?

Comment: The classroomarray variable is declared inside the try statement area. Because code can fail anywhere within that block, java can't be sure that the program ever manages to create that variable (even though it can sometimes obviously reach that point). That's why you're not allowed to use a variable that was created inside a try block.

Comment: I just removed classroomarray from try and catch block and declared as String [] classroomarray at the top,I have not tried out his code in IDE so there might be few minor syntax error. Please change it if you find any. I am positive this is the way to do it.